# Looping through XML hierarchy and get all nodes with specific properties

Tags: xml, powershell

I have extracted some data from a solution which only supports some rather suspect XML exports. I need to traverse through the hierarchy in Powershell to list all objects of **type="node"**, regardless of how deep they are in the hierarchy, that have the property **"KeySecret"** and return the value of the "name" property  of this object, and the value of the "name" property of the parent object **type="Domain"** it belongs to.

Cant figure this out based on whatever **select-xml -xpath** i have tried.

Short and simple version of my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Object id="1.1622157565" type="Domain">
  <Property type="String" name="name" value="ROOTDOMAIN"/>
  <Object id="1.1131962319" type="Node">
    <Property type="String" name="name" value="AGENTLESS NODE 1"/>
  </Object>
  <Object id="1.1132169655" type="Domain">
    <Property type="String" name="name" value="SUBDOMAIN"/>
    <Object id="1.1132121638" type="Node">
      <Property type="BigNum" name="keySecret" value="1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111"/>
      <Property type="String" name="name" value="AGENT NODE 1"/>
    </Object>
  </Object>
</Object>
```

Any hints as to how to end up with this table:

```
Domain        Node
------        ------
SUBDOMAIN     AGENT NODE 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I got so far.  I hope it points you in the right direction.

```
[xml]$XML = @"
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Object id="1.1622157565" type="Domain">
  <Property type="String" name="name" value="ROOTDOMAIN"/>
  <Object id="1.1131962319" type="Node">
    <Property type="String" name="name" value="AGENTLESS NODE 1"/>
  </Object>
  <Object id="1.1132169655" type="Domain">
    <Property type="String" name="name" value="SUBDOMAIN"/>
    <Object id="1.1132121638" type="Node">
      <Property type="BigNum" name="keySecret" value="1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111"/>
      <Property type="String" name="name" value="AGENT NODE 1"/>
    </Object>
  </Object>
</Object>
"@

$keyNode = $xml.SelectNodes("//*[@*[contains(translate(name(.),'n','N'),'Name')]]") | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "keySecret"} 

$keyParent = $keyNode

do {
    $keyParent = $keyParent.ParentNode
} 
Until ($keyParent.type -like "Domain")

$output = New-Object PSObject
$output | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty Domain ($keyParent.ChildNodes | Where-Object {$_.type -eq "String"}).Value
$output | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty Node $keyNode.NextSibling.value

$output
```

keyNode : selects all nodes from the XML that are like `'Name='` and then selects anything that is like `'keySecret'`

The Do,Until loop will search up the Parent Nodes until the Parent Node type is 'Domain'.  This will let you find a node buried deep in the hierarchy.  The 'Domain' node is set as `$keyParent`.

Comment: Oh thanks a bunch, this was definitely not something I could have imagined. Only issue - in the real life scenario the "name" property is not necessarily NextSibling from the KeySecret field. For most part (perhaps all, it's 30MB XML file i haven't verified), it will be the 3rd next sibling from KeySecret so I either need to address it specifically or somehow skip 2 siblings.

But definitely a huge step and something that is very close to being perfect for me :)